# Parsing LDAP-like string into nested object (javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, list, recursion, tree

I'm trying to parse the following LDAP-like string into an array of nested objects (see below):

```
(&(&(|(src_ip/=10.10.10.1)(dst_ip/=10.10.10.1))(|(src_ip/=10.10.11.1)(dst_ip/=10.10.11.1)))(raw=*))
```

I have tried the ldap-filters js library but it doesn't support other operators like "/=" or "!=" in between key value pairs. Hoping to end up with this object after parsing:

```
{
      "type": "group",
      "comp": "&",
      "filters": [
        {
          "type": "group",
          "comp": "&",
          "filters": [
            {
              "type": "group",
              "comp": "|",
              "filters": [
                {
                  "type": "filter",
                  "attrib": "src-ip",
                  "comp": "/=",
                  "value": "10.10.10.1"
                },
                {
                  "type": "filter",
                  "attrib": "dst-ip",
                  "comp": "/=",
                  "value": "10.10.10.1"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "type": "group",
              "comp": "|",
              "filters": [
                {
                  "type": "filter",
                  "attrib": "src-ip",
                  "comp": "/=",
                  "value": "10.10.11.1"
                },
                {
                  "type": "filter",
                  "attrib": "dst-ip",
                  "comp": "/=",
                  "value": "10.10.11.1"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "filter",
          "attrib": "raw",
          "comp": "=",
          "value": "*"
        }
      ]
    }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: why dont you replace != and /= for ~= so that ldap-filters js library works

Comment: @juvian, i see where you are going with this... string replace('~=','/=') after the parsing, could work - thanks!

Comment: Yes it should be ok if you make replacements to your string prior to parse it : replace `(attr!=value)` with `!(attr=value)` and `/=` with `~=`.